# Apache cordova plugins which work on Windows, android, ios?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is someone out there maintaining a list of apache cordova plugins which work 100% on all 3 platforms mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?platforms=cordova-windows%2Ccordova-ios%2Ccordova-android) and sort by quality

Besides, they are lot of plugin which are on Github and which can be update directly with Cordova.